# Does anywhere exist a document of solutions to Collins' Foundations of Perturbative QCD?

Tags: education, quantum-chromodynamics, specific-reference

I and some classmates are recently teaching ourselves the famous book [*Foundations of Perturbative QCD* by John Collins](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/foundations-of-perturbative-qcd/F2869ED00FBD67B65EB7829879F3EDC4) via a form of regular peer reading group. We find that exercises in this book are really worth working on. But, as a group of relatively junior students, we are hesitating to go deeper before finding a way to verify our answers. One obvious solution must be to consult some more senior researchers. But, other than that we want to know whether there exists a document of solutions to this book, so that at least we can self-verify even if we fail to find such a senior mentor.